# running rsync with absolute path from within a bash script

Tags: bash, rsync, relative-path, absolute-path

I am trying to run the following rsync command from within a bash script on OSX

`rsync -rav -e "ssh -i $KEYPAIR" --exclude ".git" --exclude '*.pyc' $SRC $DEST`

The problem is I can't get rsync to use `$SRC` as an absolute path. It always includes the relative dir from which I'm calling the bash script. Even if I prepend the path with `~/`. Is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the value of `$SRC` is not starting with `/`, can you check this? If it does not start with `/` (ie. `mnt/drive/`), will be treated as a relative directory inside the current one. But if it starts with `/` (ie. `/mnt/drive`) it should work as you expect.